# Regular expression to find the words with specific start and end characters

Tags: java, regex

I have a some text copied from the internet. It contains lot of places, those I have to remove. Few lines and occurrences are these:

```
"
related to such contracts.[79]
References[edit]
smart contract platform.[65][66]
Quorum.[63] It's designed

separate version became Ethereum (ETH) with the theft reversed,[12] 
and the original chain continued as Ethereum Classic (ETC).[13]

"
```

I tried using help on the internet:

```
^[\[]* [\]]$
```

I have to delete all `[*]`. And I have to get below output.

```
"
related to such contracts.
References
smart contract platform.
Quorum.It's designed
separate version became Ethereum (ETH) with the theft reversed, 
and the original chain continued as Ethereum Classic (ETC).

"
```

Comment: Replace `\[[^\]]+\]` with an empty string. Demo: https://regex101.com/r/YQSyzH/1

Comment: Or, simpler, using the non-greedy `*?` operator: `\[.*?\]`.

Comment: Thanks friend @41686d6564, but few places still showing,  "Ethereum (ETH) with the theft reversed,[12] and the original chain continued as Ethereum Classic (ETC).[13]"

Comment: @Sun Seems to work just fine: https://regex101.com/r/N7JOSJ/1

Comment: @41686d6564 Thanks friend, it is working.   \[[^\]]+\]

Answer (score -1):

Is it what you're trying to achieve ? Please confirm.

`(?:\[\w+\]*)`

Test here : https://regex101.com/r/nr0H99/2

Comment: Note that this won't match `"[1.5]"` or `"[foo-bar]"`. Also, the non-capturing group and the `+` are redundant.

Comment: You are right, the `+` is redundant !
_Note that this won't match "[1.5]" or "[foo-bar]"._ I was thinking there might be only numbers and characters. I think it is greedy to match anything between ``[ ]``, but since it can be a string, why not matching anything. I have update the answer.